# 802.1x Wifi with NPS Server, using EAP-PEAP and a certificate for Authentication

Tags: 802.1, nps, eap, peap

I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible but here we go.

I have a bunch of iPad's that I am going to supervise before they go on to my network.  The iPad's will connect to the wifi via 802.1x authentication using username and password from active directory via NPS server.

What I want to do is make sure that every iPad on my network has been supervised before they can connect to the wifi.  What I was hoping to do is, create a generic certificate from NPS that I can put on all the iPad's during supervision and then the iPad's can connect to the wifi using username and password.  If they don't have the certificate on the iPad, the wifi doesn't connect.

Is this a possibility?

The reason I still want the users to connect with username and password is, those details are put into our MDM, and Wifi controller.  I am not able to push a Wifi payload when supervising doing this because I have to specify a username, but I can add certificates.

Comment: for simplicity, you can make a policy with a combination of user credentials and MAC address of the device. Only those devices (in your case iPADs) will be connected whose mac will be there in your authentication server.